# Voxelize 3D objects from .OFF and .OBJ files

Tags: c++, opengl

I need a C++ program which allows to voxelize 3D models (From .Obj, .OFF,...) and provide the result in the same format of file (.obj, .OFF).

Comment: The best way to get such a program would be to write it, debug it, test it, and then you will have it for good, as well as the knowledge of how to do such a thing in the future.

Comment: To build upon Silas's comment, a good library for reading/writing various 3d files is [assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Look into [`binvox`](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~min/binvox/) and/or [`poly2vox`](http://advsys.net/ken/download.htm) for the voxelization step.

You'll have to roll your own voxel-to-OBJ routine.  But that should be pretty easy depending on how sophisticated you want to get.

Comment: Given the fact that .OBJ is a file format for triangulated meshes it's not really suitable for voxel data. A far better choice for voxel data is OpenVDB: http://www.openvdb.org/

Comment: Think you for answare.
I don't know how I can convert the .binvox into .OBJ!

Comment: OpenVDB even provides you with converters between Polymeshes and Volumes.